# how to use font family like professional in android studio

Tags: android

Is, any professional font family available on android. If it is not available, then how to use professional fonts in android. Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you mean in your application or in the complete system? Why are the existing fonts not professional enough?

Comment: As @KenY-N told that  What's your requirement ?

Comment: @KenY-N I mean in android studio

Comment: @Shailesh I tried with the available font style in android. when compare to some professional applications like Flipkart and amazon. My application is not looking that much pretty in font wise.

Comment: Because i think you don't used Flipkart and amazon app font. First you need to check that which font is used in Flipkart and Amazon and use that font in your whole app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a font to your App, place the font file in asset folder and use the following code to set it to text view...

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
        "fonts/digital.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(typeFace);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jayamurugan. what is digital.ttf whether it  is a professional font family or something different.

Comment: It is a font used for example... it is used for displaying digital timer

Comment: Try this for selecting professional fonts...http://www.creativebloq.com/typography/professional-fonts-31619557

Comment: If you got what u looked for...then accept my answer as correct answer...:) Thank u

Comment: If we want to use HalveticaNeue on android where I can refer?

Comment: You can download it from below link...http://www.freefontsdownload.net/free-helveticaneue-font-74318.htm or https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95916177934543317

Comment: Thanks, @jayamurugan. please add the above link also in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can flow this step:

```
1.Go to the (project folder)

2.Then app>src>main   
3.Create folder 'assets>fonts' into the main folder.    
4.Put your 'abc.ttf' into the fonts folder.


 AssetManager am = context.getApplicationContext().getAssets();

    typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(am,
            String.format(Locale.US, "fonts/%s", "abc.ttf"));

    setTypeface(typeface);
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the fonts follow this link.

https://fonts.google.com

These are the google recommended fonts.